# How register Flask Blueprints from config like apps in Django?

Tags: python, django-apps, flask

How I can register Flask Blueprints from my config like apps in Django?

I would like to define Blueprints in the configuration file, which will be automatically registered

```
#config.py
BLUEPRINTS = (
'news',
'files',
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually have been sketching out something like that in a project tentatively named [Hip Pocket](https://github.com/svieira/HipPocket).  It's basically the same answer as @HighCat has given you, except it uses Python's packaging system rather than a `config.py` file (although it could be extended to autoload from a config file instead - [issues](https://github.com/svieira/HipPocket/issues) and [pull requests](https://github.com/svieira/HipPocket/pulls) are most welcome.)

So in Hip Pocket you'd do this (see [`hip_pocket.tasks`](https://github.com/svieira/HipPocket/blob/master/hip_pocket/tasks.py) for how it works):

```
from flask import Flask
from hip_pocket.tasks import autoload

app = Flask(__name__)
autoload(app)
```

`autoload` walks a package (named "apps" by default, although you can change it by passing in the keyword arg `apps_package`) looking for `flask.Blueprint` objects to register on the application (by default it looks for a symbol named `routes` in a module named `routes` in each sub package it finds but those defaults can be changed as well.)  Your folder layout *might* look like this:

```
+ you_app
. . . . __init__.py
. . . . app.py
. . . . + apps
        . . . . __init__.py
        . . . . routes.py # contains the declaration `routes = Blueprint(...)`
        . . . . + news
                . . . . __init__.py
                . . . . routes.py     # Ditto
                . . . . some_module.py
        . . . . + files
                . . . . __init__.py
                . . . . routes.py     # Ditto
                . . . . # etc.
```

Alternately, if you want to use a config based loader, you could just do this:

```
 from flask import Flask
 from werkzeug.utils import import_string

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config.from_object("your_app.config")

 for tool_path in app.config["BLUEPRINTS"]:
     tool = import_string(tool_path)
     app.register_blueprint(tool)
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask is not Django, it doesn't have such features.
If your really need this, you can try to implement this behaviour yourself:

Assume you have central Flask application file with:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
```

1. Put your BLUEPRINTS variable into flask's config (the one you register with app.config.from_pyfile(...)), so it will be accessible via app.config['BLUEPRINTS']
2. In your central application file (where you do app=flask.Flask(__name__)), just iterate over app.config['BLUEPRINTS'], try to import them from the places where they can be, and register them with app.register_blueprint().

Comment: I understand that Flask is not a clone of Django and I need to implement it yourself. Basic I know that I need to iterate the app.config['BLUEPRINTS'] and use `__import__`. But how then register an imported by `__import__` Blueprint without `eval()`?

Comment: Try getattr() Smth like app.register_blueprint(getattr(\_\_import\_\_(module_name), 'the_blueprint')). If your blueprints are packages, put "the_blueprint" to each <package>/\_\_init\_\_.py