# Register dynamic blueprint

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to register blueprints dinamically?

This is the structure:

```
project
     |---app
     |     |
     |     |-------- plugin
     |     |             |
     |     |             |--- __init__.py
     |     |             |--- views.py
     |     |             |--- template
     |     |             |          |
     |     |             |          |-- plugin.html
     |     |             |--- functions.py
     |     |             |--- models.py 
     |     |
     |     |-------- plugin2
     |     |             |-- ....
     |     |
     |     |-------- __init__.py 
     | 
     |--------manage.py
```

The plugin is a blueprint:

```
plugin = Blueprint('plugin', __name__, template_folder='template')
```

In app/**init**.py

```
def create_app(config_name):
   app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
   app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
   app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

   # HERE THE IMPORTS
   from app.plugin import models
   from .plugin import plugin
   app.register_blueprint(plugin)
```

Is there a way to automatically import these blueprints?

Thanks

Comment: So every folder directly under app?

Comment: Let me explain: the "plugin" folder is a git submodule. I want to add dynamically this blueprint in "create_app". So if i add a submodule, I don't write any code in create_app to register it.

Comment: Have you already seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/11643680/135978 ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can achive this

```
import importlib

SERVICES = [
    {'path': '.plugin.views', 'blueprint': 'plugin'}, 
    {'path': '.plugin2.views', 'blueprint': 'plugin2'}
]

for service in SERVICES:
    module = importlib.import_module(service['path'], package='app')
    app.register_blueprint(getattr(module, service['blueprint']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide code by business

[image]

`app/blueprints.py`, definition of blueprints

```py
from flask import Blueprint

common = Blueprint('common', __name__)
```

`app/common/views.py`

```py
from app.blueprints import common


@common.route('/')
def ping():
    return 'pong'
```

`main.py`

```py
import importlib

from flask import Flask
from flask import Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

module = importlib.import_module('app.blueprints')
for name, blueprint in module.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(blueprint, Blueprint):
        importlib.import_module('app.{}.views'.format(name))
        app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(app.url_map)
    app.run()
```